# Font family Roboto light and bold in react native

Tags: text, fonts, react-native, font-family, roboto

I',m making some changes to the text in my react native application: I need to specify Roboto light for paragraphs and Roboto Bold for titles.
I need to have the same look of the text in both iOS and Android apps: so I need to make it work for both
I tried this code line of code

```
text    : {
       fontFamily: 'sans-serif-light'
   },
```

but I get this error: [image]

I tried this type from the official documentation and it's working fine

```
title   : {
       fontFamily: 'Cochin'
   },
```

--> So I think the problem is in the Roboto font family itself. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add custom fonts to your app store all your ttf files in a directory.
Add the following code to your package.json file.

`"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./fonts" // yours fonts directory
  ]
}`

Then run `react-native link` 
To use the font use the same name on the ttf file in fontFamily.

Comment: `react-native link`

Comment: `rnpm` has been deprecated in newer versions of react native.

Answer (score 10):

`sans-serif-light` and `Roboto` are Android-only fonts. You need different fonts for iOS. This repository has a list of fonts available for iOS and Android - https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-fonts

You can use [`Platform.select()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) to target different fonts for each OS:

```
title: {
  ...Platform.select({
       ios: { fontFamily: 'Arial', }, 
       android: { fontFamily: 'Roboto' }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you ...So, there is no way to use it on both iOS and android (because i need to look both apps to be  identical) .. i've read somewhere that i can add  it manually .ttf file and then add in the package.json and then run react native link https://hiddentao.com/archives/2017/03/10/get-custom-fonts-working-in-react-native/  .. So may that be a solution ?

Comment: Yes, if you want the same font to be used, you could add it, else keep with the default fonts

Answer (score 7):

I recently had the same issue . It turns out that `rnpm` command is deprecated and you can add custom assets using react native cli configuration. 
https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

To add fonts in the project:

- Download the font and place it in the assets/fonts folder

Create a file in the project root directory as `react-native.config.js`
Add the following code

```
module.exports={
    assets:[
        "./assets/fonts"
    ]
}
```

Run  `react-native link`

Run the project : `npx react-native run-ios`

Note: if build failed for IOS, open xocde workspace settings and change the build system to Legacy Build System.

Answer (score 5):

### Setup Roboto for both Android/iOS:

#### Usage

As Roboto is the default font family for Android. We can add Roboto to iOS and just use [RRikesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779198/1489446) solution omiting `fontFamily` for Android:

```
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native'

const stylesByPlatform = Platform.select({
  ios: { fontFamily: 'Roboto' },
  android: { },
})

export default StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    ...stylesByPlatform,
    color: '#000000',
  },
})
```

#### Setup

For iOS we need to add Roboto fontFamily:

1. Download Roboto font from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)
2. Add it to your assets folder `./assets/fonts/Roboto`
3. [Add assets folder to your package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781439/1489446):

   ```
   {
     ...
     "rnpm": {
       "assets": [
         "./assets/fonts"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
4. Run: `react-native link` (it links ttf files on iOS and copy them on Android)
5. Remove Roboto files added in `android/app/src/main/assets/fonts`
6. Rebuild your app and .

I really don't know why this type of content is not in official docs. :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed walk through

Answer (score 3):

If it can help, I had a similar issue. Using "react-native link" did indeed referenced the fonts in "Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resource", but it didn't add anything to the Info.plist file.

Adding the fonts in **Info.plist** solved the issue.

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Roboto-Black.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

for react-native +v0.69, `npx react-native link` will produce an error. If you are using this version of react-native the solution is;

1. `npm i react-native-asset` or `yarn add react-native-asset`
2. create a `react-native.config.js` file in the root folder of your project.
3. Add the following to the file

   `module.exports = { project: { ios: {}, android: {}, }, assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], };`
4. create a `assets/fonts` folder at the root of your project.
5. then in the terminal, run `npx react-native-asset`.

That should solve your problem.

**NB: As of rn-v0.69, `react-native link` has been discontinued and replaced with `autolinking`, but this feature doesn't work with adding custom fonts to your project so `react-native-asset` provides the same fixes as `react-native link`.**